# Is the Higgs force a contact scalar "force" delivering mass only (so no momentum)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, particle-physics, higgs

The Higgs force is not a gauge force like constituted by photons. It's not an intermediating field but a field that interacts directly with particles, without a gauge field to mediate its presence to other particles. It doesn't push or pull since it has no vector character.

Can we say it is a contact force, say like two electrons interacting directly in a four leg Feynman diagram with one vertex (if it existed)? What does it mean it has a scalar character? That it is a force without direction? How do we interpret that? That it directly gives its mass without delivering momentum?

Answer (score 5):

You appear to harbor misconceptions about quantum forces. The Higgs force is a short range force, analogous to the Yukawa force mediated by the pseudoscalar pion.

In fact, the Higgs field itself has four components, three of which "reside" inside the Ws and the Z (vectors), so to speak; and one in the Higgs scalar. The latter induces an interaction of a range comparable to the Compton wavelength of the higgs' mass, 125GeV, so  a *thousand times shorter than the Yukawa potential's*. Millifermis (attometers), *not* a point.

There *is* a propagator in the higgs exchange.
It imparts/transfers momentum and energy, like all such subnuclear forces: these are summarized in the internal higgs propagator in the scattering diagram. (Bjorken used to call it "the real fifth force".)

As a scalar (because of even spin), it only "pulls". It, of course, couples most strongly to heavy fermions, proportionately to their mass. So the coupling to the top quark reigns supreme here.

The mediator's scalar character  makes the interaction "isotropic", like the pion's: the ensuing short range potential has no preferred directionality.

It may be conceivable your misconception is inspired by this short range of attometers, which *appears* like a contact interaction at long distance scales—even shorter than those which make the weak interaction (W exchange) appear like a contact interaction in the 4-Fermi effective theory. I.e.,  its analog of the Fermi constant is even *smaller* than the original Fermi constant.

Comment: *In fact, the Higgs field itself has four components, three of which "reside" inside the Ws and the Z (vectors), so to speak* I lost you here. The Higgs imparts momentum to the W and Z, like a photon to an electron? If the W and Z are massless, how can the Higgs impart momentum? The Higgs is a field without a source (like the photon has a charge as source)? If it's analogous to the pion, then what is the underlying force (like the gluon in the case of pions)?

Comment: With contact I mean that the Higgs couples directly to massless Z and W, like the photon (and not another electron) couples directly to an electron (the EM force is non-local).

Comment: *and one in the Higgs scalar, which, thus, induces an interaction of a range comparable to the Compton wavelength of the higgs' mass, so a thousand times shorter than the Yukawa potential's*   But what's the nature of this interaction? How does it give rise to mass of the W and Z? It's not by pulling. By inserting mass directly in the W and Z?

Comment: I wanted to make sure you are talking about the higgs particle and not the Higgs field, which counts as 4 particles. Yes, the higgs "pulls an electron" like the pion pulls a nucleon. Mass less particles, like photons, may absorb momentum from another particle. All massive fermions can serve as a source for the higgs. The underlying force is the 5th force. The higgs couples as directly to an electron as the photon does.

Comment: The higgs particle is not involved in the Higgs mechanism, so it does *not* give mass to the Ws and the Z: the Higgs field does. You have been misinformed.

Comment: The way the Higgs field gives masses to vector bosons is *completely different* than the way it gives masses to fermions, of course. The latter is SSB,  quite disjoint from the Higgs mechanism.

Comment: I know it's the higgs field and not the particle. But *how* does the field give a Z or W mass, while being massless first? The virtual field of photons acts between electrons, but how does the condensate of higgs deliver mass? If I were a massless Z what would happen to me?

Comment: Why cant the 5th force be a gluon like force and the weak force actually be residual, like the strong nuclear force mediated by massive pions? (So actually 4 forces) Why aint there a higgs mechanism for massive pions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134218/discussion-between-cosmas-zachos-and-felicia).

Comment: A quick note: a "scalar" refers to zero spin, not more generally to even spin.

Comment: @Chris Of course! I am just nodding to the general fact that even spins induce attractive forces, so, even if the Higgs were a spin two, like the graviton, its Born-term exchange amp would also induce an attractive force, unlike a vector exchange with a nontrivial C (thus, attractive *or* repulsive). I packed too  much in there ...